# Share Excel file that queries a database

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, odbc, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a read-only file that queries a SQL Server database and will provide the information personalized for the specific user. (Excel identifies the  user and then runs the query based on the users id). What I was wondering is if there is a way to share the file without having to setup an ODBC connection for each user?

For right now I have it working for four users, but to get to that point, I had to setup ODBC on each machine. Since the file will eventually have about 60 users I was hoping there was a way for it to query SQL Server without having to setup that many ODBC connections?

Comment: What yuo want is called a DSN-less connection, and yes yuo can do it in Excel, although I am having difficulties finding a simple guide.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [DSN-less connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165866) for a guide